# Limit RSS feed to previous calendar month

Tags: filters, rss, date-query

I want to filter my RSS feed to only show posts in the previous calendar month. I have this code in my theme functions file but it is not working?

```
// filter the RSS feeds to show only the last calendar month
$lastMonthNumber = date( 'n', current_time( 'timestamp' ) ) - 1; // work out the previous month number
function feedFilter($query) {
  if ($query->is_feed) {
    $query->set('date_query', array(
        array(
           'month' => $lastMonthNumber
           //'month' => 5
        )   
    ));
  }

  return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts','feedFilter');`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach doesn't work for January:

```
$lastMonthNumber = date( 'n', current_time( 'timestamp' ) ) - 1;
```

as it would give `1 - 1 = 0`.

Here's another suggestion, using the *string to time* support of the date query:

```
$query->set( 'date_query', [ 
    [ 
        'after'     => 'midnight first day of last month', 
        'inclusive' => true,
    ], 
    [ 
        'before'    => 'midnight first day of this month', 
        'inclusive' => false, 
    ]  
] );
```

For example this should generate:

```
wp_posts.post_date >= '2018-05-01 00:00:00' AND wp_posts.post_date < '2018-06-01 00:00:00'
```

if the current day is *27th of June 2018*.

Note that `pre_get_posts` is an *action*, not a *filter*.